# In sand box account(test account) echeck payment option not visible

Tags: paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

i want to test echeck type of payment on sandbox account for testing how is it works. But how can i check because i tried a lot but echeck type payment selection option not visible on change method option

what can i do ?

for testing it....please reply...........thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently not a way to test eCheck payments in the sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer i got from paypal : 
Unfortunately there is currently not a way to test eCheck payments in the sandbox. A feature request has been submitted to our product development team for possibility of adding this feature in future system releases but there is currently no estimation on when this will be implemented. I apologize for the inconvenience.